# Python code stopped working when updating Teradata version

Tags: python-3.x, teradata

I am using the teradata module for python.
Previously I had two lines of codes that were working.
After upgrading from Teradata 15 -> Teradata 16 the code below stopped working.

```
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="my_app", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method = "odbc" , system = 'SERVER_NM' , username = 'usrnm', password = 'passw', authentication="LDAP")
```

I am getting the error message:

Any ideas of how I can fix this. Please let me know if you need additional information.

> raise DatabaseError(i[2], u"[{}] {}".format(i[0], i[1]), i[0])
>   teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

Comment: I am assuming the upgrade was to Teradata Tools & Utilities client software / drivers (which includes the ODBC drivers)? Double check your ODBC ini (and ODBCINST ini) to be sure they point to the new software.

Comment: IM002 is "Data source name not found and no default driver specified". Because this is Windows, you won't have ini files for ODBC. If you set up a new DSN, be sure you use the correct 32-bit vs 64-bit for your application.

Comment: Those are good points Fred, thank you. It seems however like the python package"teradata" doesn't support teradata version 16 yet. I will try another package instead.

Comment: You may need to add `driver = 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver xx.yy'` to your connection string (where xx.yy is the actual driver version, eg. 16.20).